# Image browse and upload buttons are not showing in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am new in Magento...Installed 1.7 community Edition.

I am trying to add images to a Product but 'Browse files' and 'Upload' buttons are missing from the backend.

If any one found solution to this problem please let me know.

Comment: I don't think so this is a irrelevant question. Everyone knows how poorly magento is documented and we need solutions like this to be available to the community so beginners do not stumble over such issues and waste their time. The only problem is this question should have been asked or moved to magento.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These buttons are coming from flash.So check your media folder on following location

design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

if there is no media folder then copy from fresh magento

This will solve your problem :)

Comment: You may need BOTH skin/adminhtml/default/default/media
and
design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use a browser with flash plugin installed (chromium) the buttons will not display. What you need to do is to use a browser with the flash plugin (ex: google-chrome).

If you are on chromium, you can use the developer tools (F12) and you will if the error come from missing flash plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Its mostly comes from browser fist check it on any other browser if work fine just reinstall your browser.

Answer (score 1):

In mozilla, these buttons will load a little bit slowly. Try to load the page in chrome. I had the same problem when I was new to magento.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, but i decided to do some little trick  and it worked, so let me share with you guys. I placed in it a label like this     <label for="" class="shadow-lg font-weight-bolder"> <input type="file" name="no_children" class="form-control">Upload Image</label>